Podman container permissions
Please help me. I try to start rabbitmq container with external volumes for configuration, mnesia and log folders. My start command looks like:
podman run --rm --name rabbitmq --hostname rabbitmq -p 1883:1883 -p 15672:15672 -v /srv/services/rabbitmq/etc:/etc/rabbitmq -v /srv/services/rabbitmq/log:/var/log/rabbitmq -v /srv/services/rabbitmq/data:/var/lib/rabbitmq --user $(id -u):$(id -g)  -d 446  /bin/bash -c "rabbitmq-server || sleep 6000"
where 446 is ID of image docker.io/library/rabbitmq:management-alpine on my podman.
But I can't start container. It wrote permission access error for /etc/rabbitmq folder and closed. When I logged to container end executed command ls -axvl I got nobody user owner for /etc/rabbitmq folder. I don't understand how I can change this.
I can't change permissions in the container, because I am not root
